# How do I access the data fields inside a bag in pig latin?

Tags: join, group-by, apache-pig, datafield

I am using the IMDB database to find the actor/actress with the highest rating and was in the most movies in a given year. I am trying to join the actors dataset with their ratings. Then filter the year and sort the data based on highest rating and movie count.

```
joinedActorRating = JOIN ratings by movie, actors BY movie;
actorRating = FOREACH joinedActorRating GENERATE *;
actorsYear = FILTER actorRating BY(year MATCHES '2000');
groupedYear = GROUP actorsYear BY (year,rating,firstName,lastName);
aggregatedYear = FOREACH groupedYear GENERATE group, COUNT (actorsYear) AS movieCount;
unaggregatedYear = FOREACH aggregatedYear GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (year,rating,firstName,lastName);
sortRating = ORDER unaggregatedYear BY rating ASC, count ASC;
dump sortRating;
```

The compiler says that the second line is an "Invalid field projection" but I am not sure how to access the year field after joining the two datasets. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After your join, you need to project the fields you want through to your current relation.

```
joinedActorRating = JOIN ratings by movie, actors BY movie;
actorRating = FOREACH joinedActorRating GENERATE ratings::movie as movie
    , ratings::rank as rank, ratings::year as year, actors::firstName as firstName
    , actors::lastName as lastName;
```

I'm not sure which columns are in which table (other than movie is in both) because you didn't include the two tables, so I just guessed.  You can modify the projections as needed.